# DataBindingUtil missing inner classes

Tags: android, android-databinding

When I try to use any **DataBindingUtil** method, eg:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView()
```

I get: **Canot resolve symbol 'mothod used'**

Then I checked inside **DataBindingUtil** class and the is alot of missing thing in there [DataBindingUtil.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6oFM.jpg)

I condigured gradle like this:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

This is my `DataBidingActivity`:

```
public class DataBidingActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataBidingActivity biding = new DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, 
        R.layout.activity_data_biding);
    }
}
```

My `activity_data_biding`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, so I recommend you that you must modify the type `DataBidingActivity` to `ActivityDataBidingBinding`, because it have to be matched between layout xml name and type value as I said from my answer.

And **you must remove `new` keyword before `DataBindingUtil`.**

So I modified your code.

```
import com.kick.iot.autohome.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DataBidingActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //here is my answer
        ActivityDataBidingBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, 
        R.layout.activity_data_biding);
 }
}
```

---

Did you import `import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;`?

And maybe you have to declare 'xxxBinding' value to use DataBindingUtil method. For example, when your activity layout's name is `activity_main.xml`, you can make a value of type `ActivityMainBinding`.

This type is already prepared by DataBinding Library. If you layout xml file's name was different, you must match names between xml's name and databinding type like this

> activity_main.xml => ActivityMainBinding
>
> activity_controller.xml => ActivityControllerBinding

In my case, I wrote my code like this

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: And you can have a reference on **[here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)**

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my **new**

Everything works fine now.

Comment: @BrunnoCunha You're welcome and you can select my answer by clicking ' v ' shape on my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added the following

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

and in `activity_main`  add `<layout>` tag as a root tag

if you do this 
- restart your android studio

Answer (score 0):

Just have just resolved same issue by restarting Android Studio. :(